# Magento2.3.2 to Magento2.3.3 update deploy error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

After Magento2.3.3 upgrade got some error like below statement.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Deploy using quick strategy
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            3148/3247           ===========================> 96%    4 secs
Compilation from source: /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
No matching definition was found for `@family-name:'Open Sans', @font-path:'../fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300', @font-weight:300, @font-style:normal, @font-display:swap` in _typography.less on line 11, column 5
09| 
10| & when (@media-common = true) {
11|     .lib-font-face(
12|         @family-name: @font-family-name__base,
13|         @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300',
14|         @font-weight: 300,
Compilation from source: /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-fonts.less
No matching definition was found for `@family-name:'Open Sans', @font-path:'../fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300', @font-weight:300, @font-style:normal, @font-display:swap` in _typography.less on line 11, column 5
09| 
10| & when (@media-common = true) {
11|     .lib-font-face(
12|         @family-name: @font-family-name__base,
13|         @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300',
14|         @font-weight: 300,

In File.php line 151:

  The contents from the "/chroot/home/html/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/styles-m.min.css" file  
   can't be read. Warning!file_get_contents(/chroot/home/html/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/sty  
  les-m.min.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Any any help me.

Advance thanks

Comment: can you check the permissions for pub and var and vendor and generated folder

Comment: @ChalaChalapathi already i checked but got error

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `.less` files with the latest variable added on 2.3.3

Check how variables that shows on dicompile error are setup in vendor for this files :

```
_typography.less 
styles-m.less
email-fonts.less
styles-m.min.css
```

Update the variables in your design directory when you overrided those files .
run

> rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* pub/static/*
>   var/view_preprocessed/*
>
> bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>   && bin/magento setup:di:compile